# file compressed the content on single line after upload in wordpress

Tags: ftp

I don't have any idea what going wrong with my wordpress file, When i tried to open a file after downloading, the downloaded file got compressed in single like like:

```
<?php/** * The Header for our theme. * * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main"> *
```

and the actual file is like:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
```

the problem with this, when i tried to upload new files then also compressed and not working properly. I have installed WP Super Cache plugin to cache the pages for increasing the page load speed with cache, I am not sure if this plugin is behind all this.

Instead of wp super cache i have added some code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

# here are few rewrite rules for 301 permanent redirect

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]


Header unset ETag  
FileETag None

<filesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
Header set Expires "Sun, 23 October 2011 20:00:00 GMT"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(css|css.gz)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, private"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(js|js.gz)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, private"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can anyone please help me what wrong i have done..

**UPDATE:**
[image]

Comment: Download the file _how_? Open the file _with what_? Please be specific.

Comment: @s_ha_dum take a look on the updated question, and hope now you understand :(

Comment: My honest answer would be ["Don't use the built in code editor, ever."](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/107028/21376) You will have to do more debugging to fix that (conceptually flawed) editor if you really want to, though. Put your `.htaccess` back to default, and disable your plugins one by one, to start.

Comment: @s_ha_dum i will keep in mind for future, but all that happening after w3total_cache plugin, and after that i deleted that plugin but all these files displaying same like above, now i have just wp super cache plugin installed and i tried disabled the plugin but same compressions files..

Comment: You mention both "W3 Total Cache" and "WP Super Cache". Which is it? Those are different plugins.

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes both are different, what happened i had wp super cache but i want to optimize my blog more so i disabled the wp super cache and installed and activate the w3 total cache but the problem i faced that all my 301 redirect link stoped working then i disabled and delete the w3total cache and re-activate the wp super cache and after that i got all that i mentioned above :(

Answer (score 0):

Caching plugins are complicated beasts. They install a number of components that other plugins typically do not. You can't just switch them off. For example, the uninstall routine for [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/other_notes/) is:

> 1. Turn off caching on the plugin settings page and clear the cache.
> 2. Deactivate the plugin on the plugins page.
> 3. Remove the WP_CACHE define from wp-config.php. It looks like define(
>      'WP_CACHE', true );
> 4. Remove the Super Cache mod_rewrite rules from your .htaccess file.
> 5. Remove the files wp-content/advanced-cache.php and
>      wp-content/wp-cache-config.php
> 6. Remove the directory wp-content/cache/
> 7. Remove the directory wp-super-cache from your plugins directory.

My guess is that you have not completely uninstalled one or both of the plugins and are seeing the consequences. You need to go through the uninstall instructions for the caching plugins and make sure that you get everything cleaned up properly.